# slf4j Logger, LoggerFactory not working at runtime from a child jar

Tags: runtime, slf4j

I am a facing an issue while using slf4j Logger and LoggerFactory in a child jar (suppose CHILD.jar).
I am deploying one EAR in **WebSphere**. The EAR structure is like below-

**Parent ear**>

- META-INF
- Project Specific dependency jars
- Project Sub Modules bundled as jars
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- common-logging-api-1.1.jar
- CHILD.jar

In CHILD.jar's MANIFEST.MF we are not giving any CLASSPTH entry as this CHILD.jar is used by several other applications and those other applications may not use any same slf4j implementor.
Below is the MANIFEST file structure-

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Build-Jdk: 1.7.0
>
> Built-By: C12560
>
> Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
>
> Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.4

In our application, we are keeping all the jar at the same hierarchy where the **CHILD.jar** is present. 
Now while deploying, no exception is thrown. At runtime, it is throwing **InvocationTargetException** (and **NoClassDefFoundError**) in all those classes where we have used **org.slf4j.Logger** and **org.slf4j.LoggerFactory**.
If we comment out all these logger entries, the application is working fine and no exception is thrown at runtime.

Even if we use org.apache.log4j.Logger **instead of** org.slf4j.Logger, the code is working at runtime(Note- log4j-1.2.13.jar is present in the same hierarchy as CHILD.jar).

**Queries-** 
Is slf4j not getting its implementor?
Any jar I have to include in the hierachy same as CHILD.jar?

**Please note-** I have tried including jcl-over-slf4j jar and log4j-over-slf4j.jar(and removed common-logging.jar) in the same hierarchy as CHILD.jar but it didn't work.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use jcl or log4j as implementor of slf4j, what you need is slf4j-jcl.jar or slf4j-log4j.jar.

Besides, when getting a NoClassDefFoundError, you should go through the full stacktrace. Usually it is caused by some other exception.

Answer (score 0):

- I recently faced this issue. Its because jars are not there in **classpath**.
- create a lib folder and add slf4j api and impl jar to it.
- use below command.
  `-cp jarName.jar:lib/* com.job.MainClass args`